# React: Is 'previousState' considered mutable?

Tags: reactjs

I've been looking around for an answer to this questions for quite a while now, so I am just going to ask:

When passing a function as the first parameter to this.setState, is *previousState* mutable?

[image: From React docs]

In the documentation it is stated that the *function(state,props)* can be used to update the state from the previous, but is it also ok to use the function like this:

Example: Assume state.profiles with user profiles and we want to change one user profile. So the question is about nested objects in state.

```
// Profiles has this structure:
// {1:{name: 'Old Name', age: 21}, 2: {name: 'Profile 2', age: 12}};

var changedProfile = {id: 1, name: 'New Name', age: 21};
this.setState(function (previousState) {
  previousState.profiles[changedProfile.id] = changedProfile;
  return previousState;
})
```

Is this ok? Can previousState.profiles be considered mutable?

Of course, the alternative would be to do something like this:

```
var changedProfile = {id: 1, name: 'New Name', age: 21},
    newProfiles = _.extend({}, this.state.profiles);

newProfiles[chanedProfile.id] = changedProfile;
this.setState({profiles: newProfiles});
```

But if mutating *previousState* is OK, then it seems redundant to me to copy the object and then set state to the copied and changed object.

EDIT: Provided a bad example at first. Replaced with better example.

Answer (score 1):

In your example your new state does not depend at all on the previous state, so you could just do:

```
this.setState({
  a: 123;
  b: {x: 'X', y: 'Y'};
})
```

However if that was just a bad example, and somehow you do need to check the previous state to determine the new state, then it would be something like this:

```
this.setState(function (previousState) {
  return {
    a: previousState.a + 123;
    b: Object.assign(previousState.b, {x: 'X', y: 'Y'});
  }
})
```

Essentially the result is that we return an object that is the new state, and we can use the previous state as we see fit - so yes, you can mutate the previous state as you did in your example

Comment: Sorry, terrible example. I've updated the question now. If previousState is mutable, then I don't get why I see all these examples with _.extend everywhere? Using React.addons.update also seems a bit overkill (unless it's used for other stuff as well).

Comment: I think the reason is that copying the current state and modifying it is clearer to understand. Whereas passing a function to setState and returning a object in the function might not be immediately obvious. I just tested this with a sample component with a initial state.x = 5; and then have a button that onClick updates the prevState object; and then print out the new state. Things works fine - I think it's just a matter of style

Comment: Alright! Thank you for answering. Think I'll look into the react source. Do you know if previousState is a deep or shallow copy?

Comment: It's actually not a deep copy. React uses Object.assign. Looks like I need to use _.merge or https://github.com/sindresorhus/deep-assign to get an actual deep copy of the state object